# How to send cookies with goutte and guzzle client 6

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, guzzle, goutte

I'm trying to access a website with goutte and guzzle, with guzzle it's working fine but when I use both together ain't working, anyone know why?

```
 $cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
            'idalmacen' => 79,
        ], 'www.publicaciones.exito.com');

        $client = new Client();
        $guzzleclient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'timeout' => 900,
            'verify' => false,
            'cookies' => $cookieJar,
        ]);
        $client->setClient($guzzleclient);

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.publicaciones.exito.com/index.php/index');
        $crawler = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
        print_r($crawler);
```